# Keep app in same order when cmd+tab

Tags: macos, keyboard

When cmd+tabing we always get the last used app in second position which I don't like.
Is there a way (setting or app) that prevents this behaviour?
I would like to keep exactly the same order in the list when cmd+tabing

Thanks

Comment: What order would you like the apps to be in then? Alphabetical, order of when they were first opened, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in the built-in application switcher. But! [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) has a macro that allows you to customize the order of the apps.[image: image of keyboard maestro showing application switcher macro]